# What versions of MVC does ServiceStack work with?

Tags: servicestack

Was curious if it will work with MVC 1.0? Looks like the mvc powerpack works with MVC 3 and 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ServiceStack hasn't been tested with MVC v1.0 (and wont be supported). The recommended versions are MVC 3/4+. If you need something more lightweight than this, consider using servicestack on its own e.g. [razor.servicestack.net](http://razor.servicestack.net).

Comment: Thanks for the reply mythz, is this an example of using servicestack on it's own?  http://servicestack.net/ServiceStack.Hello/   I ask because I am confused since the base ServiceStack is 3.5 dotnetfx.

Comment: I have an existing MVC 1.0 application and I am trying to determine what is the best course of action to use ServiceStack restful services as the DAL, from what I can tell though the best course of action would be to upgrade the my MVC application to MVC 4.0 and host servicestack from an /api folder, so that I can utilize the powerpack, but I also wonder if I could avoid upgrading my app right now and use ServiceStack as stand alone services dal and just make json push/pull requests for data and still be able to benefit from not using asp.net session state in my MVC 1.0. Sorry I am confused.

Comment: Not sure what the question is, but ServiceStack core doesn't have a dependency on MVC itself and just uses standard ASP.NET Http Handlers so it should work (since they're un-related libraries), but we haven't tested this configuration or are supporting it.

Comment: Ok, so if I use SS standalone as a dal and I wanted to consume it with a separate mvc 1.0 application what client usages could I use? I guess I am confused if it is better to use SS stand alone or under an existing framework like MVC 3 or 4 in order to reap the benefits of better caching and session state implementations.

Comment: There just libraries, you can reuse the same impls irrespective if its standalone or hosted with MVC

Comment: I can create another question for this I guess. I was hoping to take advantage SS session state and caching, but if it is stand alone, I am not sure if I still get the benefits of the SS session state and caching or not, Maybe a better question is what does ServiceStack MVC powerpack do that I don't get in the SS base library. I will create a new question for this.